# Use youcompleteme with IAR project

Tags: json, vim, iar, youcompleteme

I works happy with youcompleteme for CMake + ARMGCC project, adding `SET(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)` can make the build generate the `compile_commands.json` file, and it works with Vim YouCompleteMe.

However, when turn to IAR project, when I use `-jsondb` to generate a `compile_commands.json` as well, it can't work with YCM.

I am using a `hello_word` example from [NXP MCUXpresso](https://mcuxpresso.nxp.com/en/welcome). For the IAR workspace, YCM shows a lot of warning messages for every function call

```
Implicit declaration of function 'xxxx' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

and can't use `YcmCompleter` to jump to the definition.

[image]

Totally don't have a clue, I am attaching the compile_commands here : [ARMGCC](https://gist.github.com/ericsunplus/19a62cf7945a9cf6c26d3bc958c0f017) vs [IAR](https://gist.github.com/ericsunplus/49016051c19efc456196a6825b4c17e6). Can someone help me find some clue why the IAR version don't work for YCM?

Comment: The string `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` indicates that you are using GCC, not IAR, as the IAR compiler doesn't use that format for enabling warnings.

Comment: @Lindydancer, the IAR json file specifies `arguments` to be `iccarm.exe` from IAR, why YCM still turns to GCC?

Comment: Can't help you with that -- I'm an Emacs man...

Comment: @Lindydancer thanks for your hint anyway, at least I have some direction to dig into

Comment: Not sure how YCM works, but clangd works with internally still using clang-tools to parse the file and as such I can imagine YCM using gcc to parse your source files. I found that the jsondb option does not produce a compatible compile_commands.json. It has extra fields, which confuses at least clangd. The type for one part and then the entries which are not for the compiler (linker, elftool, pre build command).